# How to communicate with a device without known wifi password

Tags: bluetooth, wifi

When configuring my baby camera, I just needed to press a button on the camera, and then my Android phone detected the camera, after which I could configure the camera with my Wifi settings.

I want to do something simular with a hobby project, but I have no idea how this works. How does the camera communicate with my phone? I wasn't asked to enable my Bluetooth, but it was enabled, so maybe it's using Bluetooth, but I don't think so.

Is there any other way, besides Bluetooth, to do this?

Comment: there are  two ways to provision wifi devices without wps and bluetooth: [a hackish TI way to do it](http://depletionregion.blogspot.com/2013/10/cc3000-smart-config-transmitting-ssid.html) and [new method based on extension of wifi standard - easyconnect](https://www.wi-fi.org/discover-wi-fi/wi-fi-easy-connect). Android 10 has APIs to make it work. well, probably wifi-direct will work as well